# Gradle DSL method not found: 'execute()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I tried to run a project that I was not developing for a year. I did update Gradle and now I have this error. I have tried many ways to solve the problem but whatever I do I get Gradle DSL method not found: 'execute()' error
I'm using Android Studio 3.4.2. I did try to update compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28 and then I was getting the Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs error.

apply

```
plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.ypg.technoopshop"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id               : '5ce2a7f9-2ad0-4037-9787-9f20dcac9099',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'REMOTE'
        ]
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:arclayout:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    implementation 'com.allenliu.badgeview:library:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.8'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.michael-rapp:android-material-dialog:4.0.3'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.supercharge:shimmerlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.10.0'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'net.wujingchao.android.view:simple-tag-imageview:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    implementation 'com.veinhorn.scrollgalleryview:library:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:sliding-root-nav:1.1.0'
    implementation 'me.yuqirong:cardswipelayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
}
apply plugin: 'org.fabiomsr.drawableoptimizer'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'

        }
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.11.0, 0.99.99]'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'org.fabiomsr:drawable-optimizer-gradle-plugin:1.0.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Tue Jul 23 21:38:15 PKT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

```
0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ir.ypg.technoopshop">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".other.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activites.register" />
        <activity android:name=".activites.list.Phone_list" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyB9rYuq5eL_-TT3X2s3nYvufEGAro5Y0" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activites.map"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.product.product_phone"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="technoop.ir"
                    android:pathPrefix="/phone"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.videoview"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity android:name=".activites.Threed_object" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.Gallery"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" />
        <activity android:name=".activites.Search"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.Special_deal"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activites.Setting"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".activites.Support"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```